# HTML5 DnD - Why is ghost image only working as expected AFTER dragging & dropping an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, html5-draggable

I'm trying to get a `p` element with a nested `img` to show as the ghost image when dragging.

I'm not sure how to debug this but I *have* noticed that once the images are cached or have been dragged and dropped somewhere on the page, it works as expected. I've made a MWE here:

[image: gif_of_dragging]

The smiley face is dragged on first load of the page and shows the erroneous behavior - the emoji *doesn't* show during the drag. The sad face is dragged, released, and then redragged, which results in the expected behavior - the emoji *does* show as part of the ghost image. This is true of all the images.

**What I've tried:**
I thought it might be an issue with the way the page elements are loaded, so I moved the javascript to the bottom of the body (trying to ensure all elements are loaded before the script runs). This doesn't solve the issue.

**MWE code:**
I got the emojis [from here](https://emojiisland.com/pages/download-new-emoji-icons-in-png-ios-10), but I guess any pngs you have lying around on your machine will do to reproduce this.

**index.php:**

```php
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Order these items</h2>
  <div id="main_wrapper">
    <?php
      $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("image_set.json"), true);
      echo '<div id="home_container" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">';
      $i = 0;
      foreach($json as $k => $v)  {
        echo '<p class="drag_item" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag'.$i.'"><img draggable="false" src="/images/'.$v['fn'].'" width=200 height=200>'.$v['text'].'</p>';
        $i++;
      }
      echo '</div>';
    ?>
    <div id="buffer" style="min-height:100px; width:100%;"></div>
    <div id="dropzone_wrapper">
    <?php
      for($i = 0; $i < count($json); $i++) {
        echo '<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone'.$i.'" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>';
        if($i < count($json)-1){echo '&lt;';}
      }
    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="msg"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
    var dataList = ev.dataTransfer.items;
    dataList.add(ev.target.id, "text/plain");
  }

  function drop(ev, el) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data            = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var element_to_drop = document.getElementById(data);
    let droppable       = true;

    // If the dropzone already contains something (not text due to
    // spaces in markup being counted as text), don't allow 
    // another drop to occur.
    if (el.childNodes.length > 0) {
      el.childNodes.forEach(function(obj) {
        if(obj.nodeName != '#text') {
          droppable = false;
        }
      });
    }

    if(droppable)
      el.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }

  function reset() {
    // Put all drag items back into the home container
    let home  = document.getElementById('home_container');
    let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.drag_item');

    for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
      home.appendChild(cards[i]);
    }
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**image_set.json:**

```
{
  "happy": {
    "fn":"happy.png",
    "text":"A happy face"
  },
  "sad": {
    "fn":"sad.png",
    "text":"A sad face"
  },
  "angry": {
    "fn":"angry.png",
    "text":"An angry face"
  },
  "confused": {
    "fn":"confused.png",
    "text":"A confused face"
  },
  "sleepy": {
    "fn":"sleepy.png",
    "text":"A sleepy face"
  }
}
```

**stylesheet.css:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-weight:100;
}

body {
  padding:20px;
}

h2 {
  padding:20px 0;
  font-size:4em;
}

p.drag_item {
  text-align:center;
  transition:0.5s;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.drag_item:hover {
  cursor:move;
}

#home_container, #dropzone_wrapper {
  min-height:200px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-around;
  margin:20px 0;
  align-items:center;
}

#dropzone_wrapper {
  font-size:3em;
}

#dropzone_wrapper p {
  font-size:initial;
}

#home_container {
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:8px;
  background-color:#e5e5e5;
}

#home_container p {
  width:200px;
  font-size:16px;
}

#msg {
  display:block;
  font-size:2.5em;
}

.dropzone {
  min-height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border:1px dashed black;
  background-color:#00a8bd;
}
```

Comment: I think it's browser dependent, because I've tried it, and it works for me in Chrome 81, but it produces the unexpected behavior in Firefox 76.

Comment: @KriskóTamás but that doesn't explain why it would work after dragging, releasing, and dragging again in Firefox.

Comment: Yesterday I managed to find a solution to your problem. Please check if you have any issues with it, and if not, please upvote and accept the answer. If you have issues with it, or you have ran into a problem, please comment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a bit research to find the problem. This was a bit hard for me, because Firefox was the only browser where the ghost image was not shown on the first load of the page and the first drag. I opened the `Network` tab and found out that the image is only requested on the first drag (which I don't really understand, because the images were completely loaded).

Anyways, I finally I managed to get this to work, by changing the draggable element to the image instead of the paragraph.

**index.php:**

```html
<div id="main_wrapper">
    <?php
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("image_set.json"), true);
        echo '<div id="home_container" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($json as $k => $v)  {
            echo '<p class="drag_item"><img ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag'.$i.'" draggable="true" src="images/'.$v['fn'].'" width=200 height=200>'.$v['text'].'</p>';
            $i++;
        }
        echo '</div>';
    ?>
    <div id="buffer" style="min-height:100px; width:100%;"></div>
    <div id="dropzone_wrapper">
        <?php
            for($i = 0; $i < count($json); $i++) {
                echo '<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone'.$i.'" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>';
                if($i < count($json)-1){echo '&lt;';}
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="msg"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    // get the cursor position relative to the element
    var x = (ev.pageX - ev.target.offsetLeft) + document.body.scrollLeft;
    var y = (ev.pageY - ev.target.offsetTop) + document.body.scrollTop;

    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);

    // set the parent element (the paragraph) as the custom ghost image and set the position of the ghost image (x, y)
    ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target.parentElement, x, y);
  }

function drop(ev, el) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var element_to_drop = document.getElementById(data);
    let droppable = true;

    if (el.childNodes.length > 0) {
        el.childNodes.forEach(function(obj) {
            if(obj.nodeName != '#text') {
                droppable = false;
            }
        });
    }

    if(droppable)
        el.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).parentElement);
}

function reset() {
    let home = document.getElementById('home_container');
    let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.drag_item');

    for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        home.appendChild(cards[i]);
    }
}
```

> This works pretty well in: Chrome, Edge, IE 11
>
> **NOTE:** This only works perfectly in Firefox (the paragraph text only appears in this browser)

Comment: Thanks, @KriskóTamás. The problem I have is that I want the text in the p element to also be in the ghost image.

Comment: So, I managed to make this working in Firefox, but in other browsers, the paragraph text is still not shown in the ghost image.

Comment: I've made an edit to the post. As you can see, I've used the `event.dataTransfer.setDragImage()` method to set the custom image.